# filtrar dos valores de una misma columna

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

tengo un problema con mi código, este es el enlace del dataframe:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuezUN/datasets/master/iristarea.csv

Tengo este dataframe ya con algunas modificaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo seleccionar de la columna 'especie', los elementos que correspondan a 'virginica'y 'versicolor', este fue mi código:

```
iris_df[iris_df.especie.isin(['virginica', 'versicolor'])
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-102-63f40ce19bca>", line 25
    iris_df
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Si me pueden ayudar, se los agradezco.

Comment: Te falta cerrar un corchete `]` al final

Comment: Listo, pero igual no hace nada.

Comment: Algún error por consola?

Comment: Intenta asignar ese resultado a alguna variable y luego muestralo por pantalla, y cuenta como te ha ido

Comment: Hola chicos, les cuento que como lo asignaba a la misma variable no realizaba el cambio, debía crear una nueva... no tenía conocimiento de esta parte. Mil gracias por su ayuda